# Python script perfomance issue: Read text file and remove duplicates

Tags: python, performance

so, I got a .txt file with values separated by an semicolon.
What I wanna do is extract the first column, add the values to a list but don't add duplicates.
What I came up with is:

```
values = []
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        tmpVal = line.split(';')[0]
        if tmpVal not in values:
            values.append(tmpVal)
```

Though the file is somewhat big (~706 MB), this script is running very slow (actually runs for about 10 minutes now).

Can someone point out where I can improve my code?

Thanks a million,
Jerome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possible improvement you can use is using a set instead of a list for values. this will deprecate the `if tmpVal not in values` line, which is an o(n) operation (expensive!). your code will be:

```
values = set()
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        tmpVal = line.split(';')[0]
        if tmpVal not in values:
            values.add(tmpVal)
```

and to make it more pythonic:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    return set(line.split(';')[0] for line in file.readlines())
```

or on newer versions of python (using set comprehension):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    return {line.split(';')[0] for line in file.readlines()}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a set instead of a list for values. Set membership checking will be a lot faster.

   ```
   values = set()
   ```
2. Don't use readlines(). Just iterate thru the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
values = set()
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        tmpVal = line.split(';')[0]
        values.add(tmpVal)
```